# Is there a cadence that supports ^3 ^2 ^1 in the phrygian mode?

Tags: modes

My harmony books all talk about the "phrygian half cadence" which is just a half cadence usually approached from iv6. I don't know why this is called a phrygian cadence because it is not a cadence in phrygian at all. This is not what I am talking about here. in the phrygian mode the intervals in the melody would be ^3 ^2 ^1 (so G, F, E in E phrygian) which chords would support such a cadence?

Answer (score 5):

The danger of applying tonal concepts to modality is that, in modality, one generally avoids melodic or harmonic movement that suggests tonality. It is important in modality to prioritize the unique sound of the mode in contrast to major or minor.

With that said, I'll consider an answer in terms of triadic harmony.

The characteristic that separates phrygian (modality) from both major and minor (tonality) is the second scale degree, and to a lesser extent, the relationship between the third between scale degrees 1 and 3 when combined with scale degree 6 or 7. (Like the dorian scale, there is a minor third between scale degrees 1 and 3, but a "raised" 6 and 7.)

So, looking at just a melody of 2-1, the most characteristic sound would be II-i. vii-i could also be effective, since the 2-1 motion will help distinguish the cadence from the same chord progression in dorian. v<sup>o</sup>-i is likely least effective, because it could too strongly suggest a deceptive cadence in C major.

Adding the 3 to the melody would allow for the III, i, and VI chords. All of these are risky: III because it so strongly suggests a tonal dominant chord; i because it undermines the cadence by arriving at i "early"; and VI, because it will tend to sound like a tonal I chord. Thus, III is probably the best choice, and perhaps VI if arrived at carefully.

Now we have four possible cadences:

- III - II - i
- VI - II - i
- III - vii - i
- VI - vii - i

Or, thinking in E phrygian:

- G - F - e
- C - F - e
- G - d - e
- C - d - e

Of these, III - II - i will sound distinctly phrygian, especially because the III - II setup is not an especially tonal sound (in C major, G-F would be "backwards", so using it in E phrygian is less likely to suggest C as the destination). Similarly VI - vii - i is reasonable, because the same progression doesn't apply in major and would be VI - VII - i in minor.

The other two, VI - II - i and III - vii - i are a little risky, because the first two chords suggest I - IV or I - iv relationships, again conjuring tonality.

Comment: I have the best luck preventing a mode from slipping into major/minor tonality if I avoid the tritone in consecutive chords.  That's why G-F or G-d progressions fail; each has first a B and then an F, which strongly points to C as tonic

Answer (score 3):

The "phrygian" aspect of a phygian cadence is the half step movement of the bass from lowered `♭^6` down to `^5` which *analogous* to `♭^2` to `^1` in the actual phrygian mode.

The history you want for a cadence in phrygian is in the *clausula vera* which is when the two outer voices approach the final/tonic by steps in contrary motion - either expanding `^2` to `^1` and `^7` to `^1` or converging `^7` to `^1` and `^2` to `^1`. So, `^3 ^2 ^1` in phrygian would be harmonized for a cadence as `? ^7 ^1` with the `?` possibly being `^6`.

Naturally, the next question is how to harmonize it with 3 or 4 parts. My cheatsheet guidelines come from *[Helmore, Plain-Song](https://imslp.org/wiki/Plain-Song_(Helmore%2C_Thomas))* (pp.94-96)...

[image]

- The cadence in question then ends as `♭vii(min)` to `I(maj)`.
- The general style of those harmonizations is Renaissance rather than Medieval/chant
- Phrygian mode is not what many people expect, it isn't like the natural minor scale with a lowered `^2`, in modern terms it's a lot more like harmonic minor ending on a half cadence, the important thing being an end on a major triad, if you were in `C` the authentic mode ending will be `B♭m C(maj)` and in plagal mode `Fm C(maj)`
- You can think of phygian mode having an "upside down leading tone" meaning that the characteristic half step move to the tonic/final is from *above* `♭^2` down to `^1` rather than *below* `^7` to `^1`.

There is a reference given somewhere on this forum about the transition from the modal to major/minor system, which summarizes as three main tonalities eventually developed: major, minor, and... _phrygian. I really like that, because phrygian harmony is oddly and wonderfully different than major or minor. If it isn't clear, the point really is that the other modes like dorian, lydian, etc. really tend to just be "flavors" of major or minor, but phrygian is a uniquely separate tonality.

Comment: Thank you. Why can't the cadence happen another way? for example by descending 5th? In a traditional cadence there are a large number of ways of making a tonic chord sound like a tonic chord. Why must the chord be approached by step as you say? surely this descent could happen in any of the vocies for it to still sound like iii is the tonic chord.

Comment: @Armani, if the bass were desc. fifth ^5 to ^1 how will you harmonize ^5? The root position triad with ^2 above would be a diminished chord, very uncharacteristic for modal harmony.

Comment: I would play through those harmonizations in the Helmore book pp. 94-96. After a while you should get a feel for modal harmony. Root progressions by step using contrary motion are common, but roots by 4th/5th are used too, avoid the tritone harmonically and melodically, notice where accidentals are used (to make leading tones, to avoid tritones, to make major tonic chords.

Comment: Ahh ok I get it, the V chords is diminished so it cant work. i will play around through your examples. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The phrygian half cadence is mostly a tonal concept I believe, rather than modal. If you want to know about traditional modal cadences, that would be described in terms of voice leading. For the most part, a modal cadence has the notes above and below the final note in the outer voices, moving to the final note.

The next step is avoiding tritones. That leaves the "chord" choices to be F major or D minor, as others have said. However, I don't think anyone has mentioned another crucial step, which is to use a *suspension* with those penultimate notes. One of the most idiomatic cadences is to have one voice on E, then another voice sings D or F, then the first voice moves to the other note, and finally they resolve together. That will give you a classic sound.

If you want examples, listen to vocal music by Johannes Ockeghem. I hear true phrygian cadences in his music all the time, and he frequently ends the entire piece with them.

Comment: Or you can try Ockeghem's _missa cuiusvis toni_ to see cadences that work in all modes.

Comment: I've heard a movement from that while listening to his music on shuffle. I didn't know that about it. I'll have to look more into it. My composition teacher recommended him because I love pre-baroque counterpoint, and I hadn't heard much from him. Love his stuff now.

Comment: That reminds me of the Prelude and Fugue in C major by Shostakovich. In the fugue, it is pandiatonic and the subject shifts by modes. It's also a very pleasant piece. But it might not be the best for an example of traditional modal use.

Comment: Do you think a cadence with a #4 might be used for a traditional phrygian cadence? I've heard #4 used in many "major" mode cadences, like G major or E minor to F major. I tried that in phrygian using a Bb major chord, or maybe it would technically be an A# major chord. It sounded really good to me, but I'm not sure if it's traditional.

Comment: The Ockeghem was the first piece of the period I sang.  Come to think of it, if I remember correctly, we did it in Phrygian.

Answer (score 0):

> My harmony books all talk about the "phrygian half cadence" which is just a half cadence usually approached from iv6. I don't know why this is called a phrygian cadence because it is not a cadence in phrygian at all.

I define a phrygian half cadence as a cadence into the key's dominant (therefore a *half*-cadence), where the root note of the targeted dominant is reached by a half-step downwards, a so-called *phrygian second*.

So in the key of A major, the dominant is E major, and you want to precede the e note of the E major chord by an f, leading to the e with a phyrgian second. The problem is now, that the f is not within the selected key of A major, but Bdim-E7 for example sounds great for harmonizing f-e in the melody or bass voice. It can also be interpreted as a resolving minor second suspension.

Answer (score -1):

For a phrygian half cadence with the melody g-f-e you could use the chords C-F-C7, or Gm-F-C7, which is heard as a cadence to C7 as the dominant of F major key.